# Git Changes and Git Repo in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio

Why, in the dropdown menus at the top of Visual Studio 2022, are "Git Changes" and "Git Repo" in the "View" dropdown, rather than the "Git" dropdown? I understand it's something that is part of the view, but to me it seems like it's more directly related to Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, those 2 options are in both the "View" and "Git" dropdown menus, but they are called different things:

- View->Git Changes = Git->"Commit or Stash..."
- View->Git Repository = Git->Manage Branches

I do think this is a little odd, since there's no way to know this until you actually try it. If you care strongly enough about it, you could [provide feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/suggest-a-feature?view=vs-2022) to Microsoft. I would search first to see if someone already suggested this change.

Note: I verified this in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.2.1.